# OpenJPA MapJoin key() throws NullPointerException

Tags: java, jpa, nullpointerexception, openjpa

I am trying to do a search on a localized string.
The strings are mapped by an Map

Here is the entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="category", schema="myschema")
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
public class Category {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    Long id;

    @ElementCollection(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    Map<String, String> test = new HashMap<String, String>();

...
}
```

Here is the query:

```
Locale locale = Locale.ENGLISH;
CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Category> criteria = cb.createQuery(Category.class);
Root<Category> category = criteria.from(Category.class);
criteria.select(category);
MapJoin<Category, String, String> tests = category.join(Category_.test);

Predicate searchClause = cb.and(
                                cb.equal(tests.key(), locale.toString()), 
                                cb.like(tests.value(), search)
                               );

entityManager.createQuery(criteria).getResultList();
```

When the query is executed, I get this stack trace:

```
[err] java.lang.NullPointerException
[err]   at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.exps.PCPath.<init>(PCPath.java:105)
[err]   at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.exps.JDBCExpressionFactory.newPath(JDBCExpressionFactory.java:302)
[err]   at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.criteria.Joins$MapKey.toValue(Joins.java:625)
[err]   at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.criteria.Expressions.toValue(Expressions.java:66)
[err]   at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.criteria.Expressions$Equal.toKernelExpression(Expressions.java:851)
[err]   at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.criteria.PredicateImpl.toKernelExpression(PredicateImpl.java:171)
[err]   at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.criteria.CriteriaExpressionBuilder.evalFilter(CriteriaExpressionBuilder.java:216)
[err]   at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.criteria.CriteriaExpressionBuilder.getQueryExpressions(CriteriaExpressionBuilder.java:75)
[err]   at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQueryImpl.getQueryExpressions(CriteriaQueryImpl.java:418)
[err]   at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.criteria.CriteriaBuilderImpl.eval(CriteriaBuilderImpl.java:83)
[err]   at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.ExpressionStoreQuery$DataStoreExecutor.<init>(ExpressionStoreQuery.java:763)
[err]   at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.ExpressionStoreQuery.newDataStoreExecutor(ExpressionStoreQuery.java:179)
[err]   at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.createExecutor(QueryImpl.java:749)
```

I have no idea what could be wrong. Apparently the key() function does not work correctly.

I am using openjpa-2.2.3-SNAPSHOT-r422266

Answer (score 0):

Smells like a bug. Please report a [JIRA against OpenJPA.](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/OPENJPA)